# I have been trying to create a text editor using assembly language, How do I make tab/enter work

Tags: assembly, x86

I finished creating navigation keys, read and write. Everything works but tab and enter keeps being buggy. Here is the code I use to check if tab and enter are pressed

```
user:
cmp ah,1ch
je ent
cmp al,9
je tab
```

Here are the codes for tab and enter

```
    ent:
mov bx,file_size
mov file_size1,bx
mov cx,1
call shift_right
mov si,offset buffer
add si,index
mov al,10
mov [si],al
call ClearScreen
call OUTPUT_BUFFER
mov si,offset buffer
inc file_size
inc index
mov x_pos,0
add y_pos,1
add si,index
inc si
jmp user

tab:
mov bx,file_size
mov file_size1,bx
mov cx,1
call shift_right_cx
mov al,9
mov [si],al
call ClearScreen
call OUTPUT_BUFFER
mov si,offset buffer
inc file_size
inc index
add x_pos,7
add si,index
inc si
jmp user
```

The buffer, is where the string is saved. The index keeps track of the index of the string. The file_size indicates the total number of characters.

If i press enter and save the file, and then I reopen the file using notepad, the enter doesn't appear.

Comment: @ped7g Ok let me try that

Comment: @ped7g ok thanks, that worked. But for some reason, once I keep entering the previous text scrolls back up. Do you know how to disable the scrolling. Thank You. For the tab, I figured it out

Comment: I gues your OUTPUT_BUFFER outputs it in a way, which does scroll the screen content. Impossible to say without even knowing what is your target platform and how you output to the screen (looks like 16 bit real mode, so you are probably under DOS, then I would expect you to write directly to text mode video ram at `B800:0000`, so nothing can just "scroll up" your video data on it's own, if you are the only one writing there. If you are using the BIOS or DOS interrupt services, then you have to pay attention to their "cursor". I would use those only for "console" apps which should I/O with DOS.

Comment: @ped7g here is my output buffer code:    
    mov di,offset file_size
    mov [di],ax
    mov bx,offset buffer
    mov si,offset file_size
    mov cx,[di]
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,0
    mov dh,0
    mov bh,0
    int 10h
    wrtittt:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,[bx]
    int 21h
    inc bx
    dec cx
    jnz wrtittt

ret

Comment: you can [edit] your question to format the code properly, but I see you are using BIOS and DOS `int 10h` and `int 21h`, so I'm not interested into disentangling that, I'm used to access the VRAM directly for both the performance and simplicity, I would rather handle my own text cursor, than bother how exactly BIOS works when you output at last line of screen/etc... (thinking about it, maybe you should post different question, with different [MCVE], as this one is solved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enter is there, but you didn't use DOS `<EOL>` sequence, which is two byte long: 13, 10. You did insert only UNIX-like `<EOL>` consisting of single byte 10, and notepad doesn't handle that well (any more advanced text editor usually will auto-detect end lines and understand UNIX style well, IIRC the wordpad and notepad++ certainly do, or of course every text editor in linux).

You can fix it by inserting the two byte 13, 10 new line sequence (or by using text editors supporting your current new lines).

It's not clear from your post what was the problem with tab, the code looks sort of OK too.

Also I guess you may want to increment `file_size` before `call OUTPUT_BUFFER`, as the data are already larger?